# android-support-23.d.ts error TS2300: Duplicate identifier

Tags: nativescript-plugin

I have followed this [guide](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/accessing-native-apis-with-javascript) to get access to Android SDK version 23 api's by changing my references.d.ts:

```
/node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android-23.d.ts
```

But now I get multiple "TS2300: Duplicate identifier" errors when running my app:

```
./src/node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android/android-support-23.d.ts:31481:18 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'ViewUtils'.
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting all "node_modules" and "hooks" and "platforms" folders fixed it.